# Getting 400 bad request when trying to redirect to main page

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I want to create a simple crud app for employee management system. When I click on add button in the browser i get redirected to localhost:9090/employees/new, however when I click on submit button instead of redirecting back to localhost:9090/employees I get an error (bad request-400) what might be the issue?

This is my employee controller

```
package com.example.crudempdep.controller;

import com.example.crudempdep.model.Employee;
import com.example.crudempdep.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public String getAllEmployees(Model model) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        return "employees";
    }
    @GetMapping("/employees/new")
    public String createEmployee(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        return "create_employee";
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:http://localhost:9090/employees";
    }


    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public void updateEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Employee e = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        if (e != null) {
            e.setFname(employee.getFname());
            e.setLname(employee.getLname());
            e.setDepartment(employee.getDepartment());
            employeeService.saveEmployee(e);
        }
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public void deleteEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(id);
    }

}
```

This is the employees.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Employee Management System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Employee Management System</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/employees}">Employee Management</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/departments}">Department Management</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class ="container">
  <div class = "row">
    <h1> List Students </h1>
  </div>

  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-lg-3">
      <a th:href = "@{/employees/new}" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"> Add Student</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class = "table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th> Employee First Name</th>
      <th> Employee Last Name</th>
      <th> Employee Department</th>
      <th> Actions </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each = "employee: ${employees}">
      <td th:text = "${employee.fname}"></td>
      <td th:text = "${employee.lname}"></td>
      <td th:text = "${employee.department}"></td>
      <td>
        <a th:href = "@{/employees.html/edit/{id}(id=${employee.id})}"
           class = "btn btn-primary">Update</a>

        <a th:href = "@{/employees.html/delete/{id}(id=${employee.id})}"
           class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the create_employee.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Employee Management System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Employee Management System</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/employees}">Employee Management</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class ="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 container justify-content-center card">
      <h1 class = "text-center"> Create New Employee </h1>
      <div class = "card-body">
        <form th:action="@{/employees}" th:object="${employee}" method="POST">
          <div class ="form-group">
            <label> Employee First Name </label>
              <label>
                  <input
                          type = "text"
                          name = "fname"
                          th:field = "*{fname}"
                          class = "form-control"
                          placeholder="Enter Employee First Name"
                  />
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class ="form-group">
            <label> Employee Last Name </label>
              <label>
                  <input
                          type = "text"
                          name = "lname"
                          th:field = "*{lname}"
                          class = "form-control"
                          placeholder="Enter Employee Last Name"
                  />
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class ="form-group">
            <label> Employee Department </label>
              <label>
                  <input
                          type = "text"
                          name = "department"
                          th:field = "*{department}"
                          class = "form-control"
                          placeholder="Enter Employee Department"
                  />
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class = "box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I set server port to 9090 so that is why I hardcoded the redirection, but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
return "redirect:/employees";
```

instead of

```
return "redirect:http://localhost:9090/employees";
```

in the post method for employees